# Checking if a string contains character sequence and unknown variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Is it possible to check if a javascript string contains a specified series of characters and an unknown character in between. For example:

```
var secondValue = 9;
var testString = "the result is 8 and " + secondValue + " as shown above";
var stringToTestAgainst1 = "the result is * and " + secondValue  + " as show above";
var stringToTestAgainst2 = "the result is * as show above";
```

How can I test these in a way so that it returns true when comparing the testString to the first value. But false when comparing it to the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
/the result is \d+ as shown above/.test('the result is 8 as shown above')
// => true
```

See [MDN's `RegExp` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

`\d+` checks for the presence of one or more digits.

**Edit**

You can check for the presence of many things, like `\d` for digit, `\w` for any alphanumeric character, etc. The reference above provides many examples.

Comment: And what if the unknown value was a variable?

Comment: @user3024235 What kind of variable?

Comment: @user3024235 see my edit. Regular expressions are pretty robust. I'd recommend checking the RegExp docs I linked above as they're pretty extensive.

Comment: I have updated the question. The problem I am having is that some of the values in the string are variables.

Comment: @user3024235 I think you could just do `\d+ and \d+`, no?

Comment: But the secondValue is fixed